# Simple Xpath filter

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a simple XML which contains a list of books:

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>9.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
. . .
</catalog>
```

I want to list all books which have price <10. So I have built the following expression:

```
/catalog/book//price < 10
```

When entered into the XPath tester window, a "True" is returned. I'd expect to have the list of books instead.
How can I adjust my XPath expression to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is correct, but it evaluates to a *Boolean* value, which is either true or false, as you have noticed. What you need is an expression that evaluates to a set of nodes:

```
/catalog/book[price < 10]
```

The part between `[` and `]` is called a predicate, which is really a "filter".